# Packaging jar file with Archetype nexus

Tags: maven, nexus, archetypes

I have created a maven archetype that archetype i created also has custom (my) jar files in it.

The clean install works fine and deploy works fine. The archetype gets created successfully.

I can also create a service based of the archetype. The problem though is, all the files come ok from nexus but the jar files are getting corrupted.

if any one can help me with a tip that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the storage directory of the repository you've deployed to, and see if the jar is corrupted there.  If it is, then it is likely an anti-virus program has altered the file (nexus streams uploaded content directly to disk, it does not alter it in any way).

Comment: No it isn't corrupted over there. I think I found the fix. If that works I shall post the solution.